# Azure build pipeline not generating bin folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-devops

I have aspnet MVC 5 solution which is containing several project, i need to publish the main project using azure CI and CD so i configured azure build pipeline (see the attachment for configuration). but when the artifacts are generated i noticed that there is no bin folder with deployment files. what could be the possible reasons for this behavior?

[This is the generated artifact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DgXc.png)

[This is Solution Configuration task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUPfF.png)

[This is the publish path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REQf9.png)

[This is publish artifact configuration task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AX6by.png)

[This is link for the logs of the pipeline](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zPbaLIb6LSkhjNVcNLUFIokcxNK7_6xX/view?usp=sharing)

[This is The error when i chose the solution instead of csproj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZFtK.png)

[This is after chaining to SLN or set AnyCPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwFMJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what could be the possible reasons for this behavior?

According to the images you provided, I could reproduce this issue if I select the **project file .csproj** instead of **solution file .sln** in the Visual Studio build task:

[image]

That because if we select the project file `.csproj`, there is a warning when we build the project:

```
Warning : The OutputPath property is not set for project 'ASP.NETMVC.csproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='release'  Platform='any cpu'.  You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this project.
```

[image]

Although the result of the task is passed, the output is not output correctly due to the above warning.

That the reason why you build is successfully, but `bin` folder is not generated.

To resolve this issue, we select the solution file in the Visual Studio Build task:

[image]

Then the warning disappeared, and `bin` folder is generated:

[image]

**Update:**

> when i select the solution instead of the csproj i got errors related
>   to the unsuccessful builds due to some missing references.

That because you just restore the one of packages.config file in the nuget restore task. You need to change it to the `.sln` file instead of `packages.config` file.

Besides, to resolve your previous issue, we could choose the `.sln` file  instead of the project file (I answered before.). Or you could change the default variable **BuildPlatform** from `any cpu` to `AnyCPU` (move the space).

Hope this helps.

Comment: when i select the solution instead of the csproj i got errors related to the unsuccessful builds due to some missing references. so i resolved this issue by pointing to csproj

please not that:
all files are generated successfully on  the current case, but only the bin folder is not.
thanks for your support.

Comment: @MohammadYusuf, please share your visual studio build task and publish artifact task log in your question, so that we could check the reason for this issue.

Comment: updated, please check the updated image, i chose the solution instead of csproj

Comment: @MohammadYusuf, I have updated my answer for the solution, check if it helps.

Comment: i do appreciate your support thanks!,
but now i'm getting another error. i have nuget packages gleamteach for document viewer, it says fa-lid to restore them and they could not found on nuget.

Comment: @MohammadYusuf, That because the package `gleamteach` is not public nuget package on nuget.org, so nuget task could not restore that package from the default feed. You need publish that package to your private feed and restore it from your private feed.

Comment: thanks for your support.

please tell me how do i can publish to my feed ?
any links or video for that?

Comment: @MohammadYusuf, Check this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-nuget?view=azure-devops.

Comment: my problem is that bin folder is created but the updated build dll is not get complied  and not placed into the artifact, instead I manually I check Out the .dll file and than checkIn and after that my changes appears